# Java: digital signature different on linux server than on windows client

Tags: java, linux, signing

I am facing a strange issue where the digital signature is different on Windows client than on the Linux server. I understand that this can occur if the encoding is different, so I changed all code to force UTF-8. Also I added some hardcoded string to see if the signatures are different, and they are.

This is the string:

```
"http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org"
```

The local signature is:

```
23d8190409b19fcfb83586b317de8ef710bd485ab5277238f2f2d3fa5daa3660
```

The server string is:

```
7bacef6d25665ae8df11f736b2612c8ebc92a160ee4ced4606c07e7a93a50338
```

Here is the signing code:

```
private String sign(String data) throws Exception {

    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            securityWebApi.getSecurityFilterConfiguration().getAzureSignatureKey());

    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");

    byte[] key = IOUtils.toByteArray(reader, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    LOG.debug("got key array : " + new String(key));

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

    String testSign = Hex
            .encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal("http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org".getBytes("UTF-8")));

    LOG.debug("test sign == " + testSign);

    String testSign2 = "Bla"
                +"bla";

    LOG.debug("test sign2== " + Hex
            .encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(testSign2.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

    return Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}
```

So all of the signatures are different. Apparently I am missing something fundamental here, but what?
Thanks for your help.

Oh yes, the server code is running in Oracle Weblogic 11g.

Of course I double checked if the Private Keys are equal, and they are.

Comment: Can you attach also the private key? (mijnnuonapi.key I suppose). If possible can you specifiy the expected results of test sign and test sign2?

Comment: Hi, above you can see the results of testSing on client and server. I can't print the api key here though.

Comment: when you log "got key array : " you have the same value comparing client log and server log?

Comment: The "file.encoding" property of the JVM running on Windows client has been set? Be sure that the value of the property on client is the same on server.

Comment: I've tried many combination but I've always the same sign. Are you sure that the method 'securityWebApi.getSecurityFilterConfiguration().getAzureSignatureKey()' return the same key when executed on client and server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue was that the keyfile was read in Linux with a LF only, the validation of the signature is done on a Windows Server. The same key file there was read with a CRLF, so that is a DIFFERENT key (byte array).

We changed the code so that the validation of the signature on Windows will remove the CR character from the key string.